# How do I apply events and effects to elements generated through Ajax request with no specific id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, event-handling

I am making a forum and I want it to run like a desktop application, so I do not refresh the page. For lack of a better method without another complete Ajax request I receive the number of pages of data available in an Ajax request. I need to display this data (as I have at ethoma.com/testhome.php -- I set the page size to 1 for testing) but I also need to add event handlers to each individual number displayed to trigger an event that will change the color of the text and trigger an Ajax call to get the page number specified. The challenge for me is that there could be 500 pages (of course then I wouldn't be able to display every page number). For those who don't want to view the code via my site, here is the important parts of it:

```
function getPosts() 
            {
                var queryString = "category=" + category + "&page=" + page + "&order=" + order;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: 'getposts.php',
                    data: queryString,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var oldHtmlTemp;
                        var dataArray = data.split("%^&$;");
                        numpage = dataArray[0];
                        $('#postcontainer').html(dataArray[1]);
                        $('#enterpage').html('');
                        if (numpage != 0)
                        {
                            for(var i=1;i<=numpage;i++)
                            {
                                oldHtmlTemp = $('#enterpage').html();
                                $('#enterpage').html(oldHtmlTemp + "&emsp;" + i);
                            }
                            oldHtmlTemp = $('#enterpage').html();
                            $('#enterpage').html(oldHtmlTemp + "&emsp;");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#enterpage').html('No results for this query');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

If you are wondering what the .split() is doing, the php doc returns the number of pages seperated by that weird string that I designated. I decided it would be the easiest way to put the number of pages within the rest of the post text.

Anyway how would I add event handlers to these individual numbers?

I have a quick follow-up question, this code isn't working for some weird reason. It adds an event handler to the next page and previous page buttons, but also error checks to make sure you aren't trying to hit page -1.

```
$("#nextpage").click(function() 
            {
                if (page < numpage -1)
                {
                    page++;
                    getPosts();
                    alert(page);
                }
            });
            $("#prevpage").click(function() 
            {
                if (page >= 1);
                {
                    page--;
                    getPosts();
                    alert(page);
                }
            });
```

Alerts are for debugging. Also worth noting is that when page = 0, you get page 1. What I mean is, I am counting from 0 1 2, but the user sees 1 2 3.

Thanks to anyone who views/answers this post.

Comment: My second sentence doesn't make any sense.... my bad, but you get the idea, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will refer to the last question first. 
I didn't understand the followup question as you didn't specify what exactly is not working. 
I am guessing you are overriding your "next","prev" while dynamically loading new HTML. 
To resolve this, take a look in the ["live" jquery method](http://api.jquery.com/live/). 
What it does is exactly like assigning "click" (like you did) but it re-evaluates the selector on each event. So the new elements will still be included.

I believe the "live" method will work on the first question as well. 
Simply wrap each number with some "span" identified by a unique "class". and add something like this :

```
$(".pagination-number").live("click",function(){
$(".pagination-number").attr("color:black"); // remove previous click color
$(this).attr("color:red"); // mark currently clicked number
 .... // load the content
})
```

When I write an HTML that loads dynamically, I always assign the Javascript to that HTML. 
This way - I reevaluate the JS when the new HTML is loaded.

For example - my returned html looks something like

```
<div class="highlight"> some content here </div>
<script> $(".highlight").effect("highlight",{},300)</script>
```

The benefit it gives me is that I assign the behavior to the data. (just like in OOP). 
I don't need to rewrite the behavior for each time I load the HTML. (in this example to highlight the text). 
It will be highlighted each time I load the HTML because the script is evaluated. 
You should consider using this design pattern as it will :

1. Concentrate all your code into a single place
2. This design pattern overcomes scenarios in which you override a dom object. ( for example, the old HTML has a #prev button, and the new html also has a #prev button. The code will always refer to the most recent dom element hence the behavior will be consistent.